# Angular distribution of neutrinos in $e^-u\rightarrow\nu_ed$ scattering

Tags: particle-physics, scattering, neutrinos, helicity

What does the angular distribution of the neutrinos look like in the scattering $e^-u\rightarrow\nu_ed$?

The tree-level Feynman diagram looks like this and since all of the fermions couple to a $W$ boson, all of them must be of LH chriality.

[image: Feynman diagram for the scattering process]

Let us choose the COM frame in such a way that the incoming electron's 3-momentum is collinear to the z-axis. Since all fermions couple to a W boson, all of them must be of LH chirality. If we consider all of the fermions as massless (which is done in the context of DIS), then their chiralities correspond to their helicities. Hence, the incoming fermions' spins must be antiparallel to their 3-momenta. If we choose to quantise their spins along the z-axis, then we find the following picture. The double arrows are the spin components in z-direction and the simple arrows are the 3-momenta in the COM frame.

[image: Kinematic diagram with spin directions]

Now, the same reasoning applies to the outgoing fermions. However, they can get scattered under an angle to the incident particles, such that a component of their 3-momenta is transverse to the z-axis and therefore also to their spins.

So I would therefore argue that the neutrinos will get scattered preferably collinear or antiparallel to the incoming electrons, since that way their helicity will be maximally LH, i.e. in a cone around the z-axis.

Does that make sense or am I talking complete nonsense?

Comment: You probably need to read up on [this](https://www.hep.phy.cam.ac.uk/~thomson/partIIIparticles/handouts/Handout_10_2011.pdf) --safe link.

Comment: I have gone through the calculations and I understand them, however I would like to know if there is a physical argument for why the scattering with $S=0$ is isotropic and for $S=1$ it is not.

Comment: I am not sure right now why *S*=0 is chosen over *S*=1... A Fierz argument? Senior moment. The rotation of your diagram, but with the arrows of your final state aligned with the momenta, like the initial state, is the amp proportional to $d^s_{00}$ which is 1 for s=0, and $\cos \theta$ for s=1. Your introduction to the helicity formalism (Jacob & Wick??) should detail that. If you scattered $\bar d    u \to \nu e^+$ it would be s=1, as the intermediate state would be a $W^+$...